# How to print multiple jobs to multiple raw files (using FILE: port in printer properties)?

Tags: windows, printing, printer

In any printer properties I can choose a port named "FILE:" to have the driver save the printout to a raw file. That works well, however, when printing multiple jobs over the windows print spooler, the file is immediately overwritten, so at the end I have only the last print job.

Unfortunately, the file name doesn't support any placeholder variables..

I was thinking about writing a tool/script quickly moving the file away when it's closed. But isn't there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This free tool installs a new port with the capability to save to a generated file name with placeholder variables:
http://mfilemon.sourceforge.net/

Tested with Windows 10 x64, but should work with previous versions as well.

After installation just click "Add Port..." in the "Ports" tab and you'll see how it works.